# How update html img src from spring controllers method?

Tags: javascript, java, html, spring-mvc

I add capcha to my JSP page (kaptcha library). It look like this

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/captcha.jpg", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public void captcha(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) throws ServletException, IOException {
        super.captcha(req, resp);
    }
```

and in page

```
<img src="captcha.jpg"/>
```

Now I need create button for update this captcha.(or when I clik to captcha image)

I tried this

```
<a href="captcha.jpg">
            <img src="captcha.jpg"/>
            </a>
```

but when I click to image it open singly. 
I need just refresh captcha image after click.

Maybe javaScript, maybe something else? How do it?

**UPDATE**

I create this

```
<script>
                function update() {
                    document.getElementById('my-image').setAttribute('src', "captcha.jpg");
                }
            </script>
            <a href="" onclick="update()">
                <img src="captcha.jpg" id="my-image"/>
            </a>
```

It work but after img update my page scroll up. how can I fix it?

Comment: HTML can't understand the difference between `captcha.jpg` in the `href` vs in the `src`. You will need to use a different URL that doesn't conflict with a file name.

Answer (score 1):

Your page is scrolling up because the default behavior of an anchor tag is to scroll to the top unless you give it a URL, an element to scroll to, or a `javascript:` statement.

To fix it, either put `javascript:` inside the the `href` of the anchor tag, or remove the anchor tag and put the `onclick` event on the image like this:

```
<img src="captcha.jpg" id="my-image" onclick="update()" />
```